# How to send long data (255 Bytes in one packet ) in ios using BLE

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, mtu

I want to send 255 byte string data in react native with **BLE**,
in android there is no problem but in ios **only 185**  byte can be sent,
I requested for mtu = 255, but no result
libraries that i tried: 
[react-native-ble-plx](https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/)
and [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager)

Answer (score 2):

iOS has fixed MTU. You need to use the "Write Long Characteristic  Values" procedure to write a longer value. This should be done automatically by iOS when you set the write type to be With Response. Just note that the peripheral needs to support prepared writes.

Comment: thanks,but as i said i want to do that in react-native , do you now some library to do that or how i can do it with that 2 libraries(ble-plx & ble-managr)?

Comment: Hi were you able to solve this?